# Sharp Architecture for Winform apps?

Tags: c#, winforms, spring.net, s#arp-architecture

The Sharp Architecture Contrib seems to suggest it is possible. It seemed like they had a dependency on "PostSharp" which has now been replaced with Castle interceptors.

Has anyone used the Sharp Architecture for a non Web project?

How was the experience?

Does that mean one is locked in with castle as the IoC container when using Sharp architecture for non web purposes?

If not Sharp Architecture, then what are some of the favored application frameworks for the non web world [spring.NET?] ?

If one were to start a green field Winforms app, what application framework would be desirable?

Comment: am I asking a valid/pertinent question or is it something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to have PostSharp, which is used for AOP logging I guess. SharpContrib has implement any way to store Nhibernate session. You can download the source code to check. I used it in a proof-of-concept application along with TopShelf (for console or windows services). It works well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there something like this to WinForms, as WinForms don't support this new principles of design. Instead, use WPF.

You would see a few libraries like this to WPF and silverlight  projects.

http://magellan.codeplex.com/
http://caliburn.codeplex.com/
http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question, I thought I'd mention [MVC#](http://www.mvcsharp.org/).  I had looked at using it for a possible redesign of a VB.NET WinForms app, but we decided to leave the application alone for other reasons (nothing to do with MVC#).